# Constexpr function to concatenate vectors

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to initialize a `const std::vector<std::string>` member object of a base class, with a vector comprised of compile-time strings passed up from a derived class. The derived class will define some of the strings in the vector, and the remainder of strings in the vector will be defined by subclasses of the derived class (i.e. classes derived from the derived class).

For example:

```
// +----------------+
// | ConfigBaseUnit |
// +----------------+
class ConfigBaseUnit
{
public:
    ConfigBaseUnit(std::vector<std::string> &&fields);
    virtual ~ConfigBaseUnit() = 0;

private:
    const std::vector<std::string> field_vector;
};

ConfigBaseUnit::ConfigBaseUnit(std::vector<std::string> &&fields) 
    : field_vector(std::move(fields)) {
}
ConfigBaseUnit::~ConfigBaseUnit(){}

// +----------+
// | Ioconfig |
// +----------+
class Ioconfig : public ConfigBaseUnit
{
public:
    Ioconfig(std::vector<std::string> &&fields);
    virtual ~Ioconfig() {};
};

std::vector<std::string> & vect_concat(
      std::vector<std::string> &&v1,
      std::vector<std::string> &&v2 )
{
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    return v1;
}

Ioconfig::Ioconfig(std::vector<std::string> &&fields)
    : ConfigBaseUnit( std::move(
          vect_concat({ "label", "protocol", "connected" }, std::move(fields))
      )
    ) {
}

// +-------------------+
// | Ioconfig_Ethernet |
// +-------------------+
class Ioconfig_Ethernet : public Ioconfig
{
public:
    Ioconfig_Ethernet();
    virtual ~Ioconfig_Ethernet() final {};
};

Ioconfig_Ethernet::Ioconfig_Ethernet() 
    : Ioconfig( { "ip", "port" } ) {
}
```

---

Here, the abstract base class `ConfigBaseUnit` initializes its const `field_vector` member with its class-constructor argument.

```
ConfigBaseUnit::ConfigBaseUnit(std::vector<std::string> &&fields) 
    : field_vector(std::move(fields)) {
}
```

The derived class `Ioconfig` wants the initialization of `field_vector` to always include these items:

```
{ "label", "protocol", "connected" }
```

but `field_vector` should also include the items sent up by `Ioconfig_Ethernet` (which is derived from `Ioconfig`). For instance, `Ioconfig_Ethernet` passes these forward for inclusion:

```
{ "ip", "port" }
```

`Ioconfig` ties these together in its constructor like this:

```
Ioconfig::Ioconfig(std::vector<std::string> &&fields)
    : ConfigBaseUnit{ std::move(
          vect_concat({ "label", "protocol", "connected" }, std::move(fields))
      )
    } {
}
```

The `Ioconfig` constructor uses function `vect_concat(...)` to merge the fields together into a final vector which it then moves to the base class.

And `vect_concat` is just:

```
std::vector<std::string> & vect_concat(
      std::vector<std::string> &&v1,
      std::vector<std::string> &&v2 )
{
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    return v1;
}
```

**Now to the point**

This works, but I would like for `vect_concat` to be a **`constexpr`** function. Ultimately, the values in `ConfigBaseUnit::field_vector` should be defined at compile time. Its contents should be inflexible, hard-coded, plain-text values, which can easily be discovered by reading the code (i.e. they will never be read in from a file, or command-line arg, etc).

Just defining `vect_concat` as `constexpr` doesn't work, presumably because std::vector::insert is not constexpr. How can I work around this?

---

**Note:** After typing out the question above, I found that declaring `vect_concat` as a template allows me to make it a `constexpr` function.

This works:

```
template <class V>
constexpr V & vect_concat(V &&v1, V &&v2)
{
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    return v1;
}
```

This does not:

```
constexpr std::vector<std::string> & vect_concat(
      std::vector<std::string> &&v1,
      std::vector<std::string> &&v2 )
{
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    return v1;
}
```

So, **my questions** (which, unfortunately, evolved during the course of writing this post) **are:**

1. What's the difference between the two functions above, that makes the template version compile and the non-template version fail? Both cases use `std::vector::insert`, which does not seem to be a constexpr function.
2. Is the `constexpr` specifier simply ignored in the template case?
3. And is using the template version the answer to my original question?

Comment: Hi @Blair Fonville, just out of curiosity, do you remain puzzled as to your question after reading my answer below? If so then I'd be glad to try and help further.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist A little. Your answer refers to specializations, which isn’t precisely relevant. Mostly though, I was just giving the question some time. Thanks for the gentle reminder.

Comment: @BlairFonville: What you are trying to do is simply impossible.  **`std::vector` cannot be `constexpr`**, ever, because its specification requires dynamic allocation.  `std::string` has a similar problem.  You should consider using `std::array<char const* const, N>` instead for compile-time lists of strings... a `std::array<char const* const, N>` concatenated with a `std::array<char const* const, M>` will result in a `std::array<char const* const, N+M>`, which the template system is more than capable of handling.

Comment: In addition to that, your function is very dangerous even as a non-constexpr approach, because **you return a reference to a temporary object** whose destruction is imminent... the caller will be left with a dangling reference.  Because you move the content out before the temporary dies, it works... but the type system is not helping you remember to do this.

Comment: @Blair Fontville Are you sure what you're referring to as *specialization* in this case isn't just the instantiated version of `vect-concat()`? As in what the pre-compiler generates when you try to call it with some `std::vector` arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The difference between the two functions [that makes the template version compile ...]** is defined according to the standard right here [[dcl.constexpr], §9.1.5.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6):

> If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function
>   template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy
>   the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor,
>   that specialization is still a `constexpr` function or `constexpr`
>   constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a
>   constant expression.

2. As you can see from the standard, the `constexpr` isn't ignored, but when you'll try using it as a constant it shouldn't compile.
3. As a whole i'd say this is only the answer to your original request in case your sole reason for having `vect_concat()` a `constexpr` was delivering intent in the code (A worthy cause in its own right!). But if at any point moving onward you're to try calling it as a syntactic constant it would reveal itself as missing the entire point of `constexpr` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Methods marked with “constexpr” will only be evaluated at compile time if the parameters passed in are also compile time known. Templates are made at compile time so it knows what is being passed in therefore it allows it to work. Then, when you pass in the initializer it can construct the vector at compile time. Otherwise “constexpr” methods are evaluated at runtime just like any other method.

Comment: The compiler generates functions for the templates depending on how the template's types are instantiated in the code. In my case, as far as I can tell, the compiler should replace <class V> with std::vector<std::string>, and I will therefore end up with the same code as my non-template case. So, I don't see how the two are different.

Comment: @BlairFonville I believe you are correct here -- the two are only different if you take into account a certain sub section of the standard's entry for `constexpr` regarding function templates. I have added an answer pointing it out and what I believe to be answering your final 3 questions in the OP. Hope this helps.